# Angular slideshow

Tags: angular, slideshow

Hi guys is there any way to create slideshow in Angular similar to this on the following website:
https://americansecurestorage.com/
but with response where the image field in database contains multiple image URLs separated by commas.
For example, this is the response from server:

```
[
   {"number" : "1", "2", "3"},
   {"image" : "image1.png,image2.png,image3.png"},
   {"text" : "someText"}
]
```

Or more specifically how to convert that part of JSON object to this:

```
imageURLs = [
   {url1: 'image1.png'},
   {url2: 'image2.png'},
   {url3: 'image3.png'},
]
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: [String.split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) with some map should get you there.

Comment: @mhdev, why you want to make this "strange" array?. sure you dont want `imageURLs = [{url: 'image1.png'},{url: 'image2.png'},{ur3: 'image3.png'}]`? you'll find in troubles to mannage in a *ngFor an array with different structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can utilize the following function to convert any comma delimited string to JSON

```
const CSV_to_JSON = (data, delimiter = ',') => {
      const titles = data.slice(0, data.indexOf('\n')).split(delimiter);
      return data
        .slice(data.indexOf('\n') + 1)
        .split('\n')
        .map(v => {
          const values = v.split(delimiter);
          return titles.reduce((obj, title, index) => ((obj[title] = values[index]), obj), {});
        });
    };
```

Example usage

```
    console.log(CSV_to_JSON('url1,url2\na,b\nc,d')); 
// [{'url1': 'image1.png', 'url2': 'image2.png'}, {'url1': 'image3.png', 'url2': 'image4.png'}];
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, all you want to do is to transform a comma separated string value `"image1.png,image2.png,image3.png"` into this format

```
[
    { url1: 'image1.png' }, 
    { url2: 'image2.png' }, 
    { url3: 'image3.png' }
]
```

**Solution 1 (using [`Array.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map))**

```js
image = 'image1.png,image2.png,image3.png';

imageURLs = image.split(",").map((x, i) => { 
    return { ['url' + (i + 1)]: x.trim() }
});
```

**Solution 2 (using [`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce))**

```js
image = 'image1.png,image2.png,image3.png';

imageURLs = image.split(',').reduce((a, v, i) => { 
    a.push({ [`url${i+1}`] : v.trim() });
    return a;
}, []);
```

Comment: why use reduce and not map?

Comment: I answered in haste, but `map` is definitely the more readable/easier version :) Updated answer with the `map` solution.